# Unique device identification for KaiOS featured phones

Tags: javascript, uniqueidentifier, firefox-os, deviceid, kaios

I am trying to find unique device identification in KaiOS featured phones such as Jio Phone. I am developing an app for featured phone using plain JavaScript and need to uniquely identify each mobile device, I am unable to find any solution for this.

Can anyone suggest any solution for the above problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the device UUID as a unique identification number. It will be the same even when the app uninstalls and reinstall again.

Get UUID using the below code.

```
var uuid = new DeviceUUID().get();
```

[Here is the full code of DeviceUUID](https://github.com/biggora/device-uuid/blob/master/lib/device-uuid.js)

[Library link](https://github.com/biggora/device-uuid)

Answer (score 0):

Mobile ID API should work, but there will be permission dialog for the user

https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI/MobileIdentity

Answer (score 0):

With caveat that with every reinstall of app, this number will change, you can generate a random uuid(https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) and store it in localstorage/idb.

this also wont need any permissions.

you can also use canvas fingerprinting without above issue or permission needs
https://www.andreafortuna.org/2017/11/06/what-is-canvas-fingerprinting-and-how-the-companies-use-it-to-track-you-online/